# Get PHP to grab all files based on how many the user chose to upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, file

I'm making an 'entry submission' form where people can input some data about something relevant to them, then use a slider to choose how many files they want to upload (0 to 10). I don't want to put all 10 file upload fields in the form because it makes my UI look bad.

So instead, I'm making jQuery code that allows the user to change the number of file upload fields they will need depending on what they want to enter.

But in my "add_entry.php" script, I was wondering how to get PHP to know whether there were for example 5 input fields or 3 input fields. Is there sort of a "get all file inputs" command?.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uploaded files are stored in the superglobal array $_FILES.
when using multiple file upload, the array could look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
    (
        [0] => foo.txt
        [1] => bar.txt
    )

    [type] => Array
    (
        [0] => text/plain
        [1] => text/plain
    )

    [tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
        [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
    )

    [error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
    )

    [size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 456
    )
)
```

using a `count($_FILES['name'])` of `size($_FILES['name'])` command, you can check the number of files uploaded.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

on above link you can find this info as well as a simple function to convert this array to a more handy format (like an array for each file instead of an array for each property)

i hope i have helped you enough with this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload many files, I would strongly recommend [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). It has a file upload queue widget that great and quite clean, bur you can also build your own custom GUI for it. It also have the ability to chunk upload big files, if you have have that need.

[The queue documentation](http://www.plupload.com/docs/pluploadQueue). (Here there is a parameter called `max_file_count` that allows you to limit the number of files a user can add to the queue.)

[The API reference](http://www.plupload.com/docs/API).

---

The answer to your question how ever is that you set the name of the file upload inputs like so: `<input type="file" name="files[]" />`

You can then in your PHP get the files like this:

```
$numberOfFiles = count($_FILES['files']['name']); // The number of files uploaded, but you can easily use a foreach loop. See below.

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $fileTmpName) {

    // Process each file here using $fileTmpName.

}
```

See this link: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php